# Issue with CapacitorHttp on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I recently switched HTTP calls from the Cordova plugin to CapacitorHttp, and having sporadic issues with IOS (only).

Using the latest Ionic 7.2.2 and Capacitor 5.2.2.  Running against a back-end web service in the cloud using "https".

Everything works fine for Android, and in the Web App -- but iOS is failing *every other* call.   Here is what I see in my logs for iOS:

Successful call to API, but just before call is made:

... **[NSURLSession sharedSession] may not be invalidated**

Unsuccessful call to API, after it has failed:

... **(NSURLErrorDomain error -1000.)","message":"The operation couldn’t be completed"**

The above cycle repeats consistently with the pattern as ... works, fails, works, fails, etc...

For the life of me I cannot find anything online that indicates what these errors are and how they pertain to my usage of CapacitorHttp.  There must be some specific configuration needed for iOS -- any ideas?  Who else has this working and care to share what your code looks like?  I am following the tutorial/examples...

Comment: Could this have anything to do with it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414823/how-do-you-know-when-the-nsurlsession-object-has-been-invalidated-by-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, though I'm not sure why it worked 50% of the time without this for iOS, nor why it always worked for Android/web.

The line of code I was missing is simply this:

```
url = encodeURI(url);
```

Annoyingly, I had this line for the Cordova plugin I used before Capacitor.  Anyway, I hope this helps someone out there who may run into the same issue.